# Comic about a human, with two small telekinetic dogs both of whom are named Eric

Tags: story-identification, comics

In the mid 1980s I borrowed a stack of comics from a friend.  Most of them were standard Superman, Batman, Spider-Man, etc. but there were a few odd ones too.

This one has stuck in my head, possibly because of its very detailed inking.

The protagonist is a human, I believe the only human seen, in a place with various aliens.  The protagonist is accompanied by an identical pair of small white talking dogs both named "Eric."  The dogs have some kind of mental powers and are able to strike down a huge (5 metres tall or more) humanoid who threatens the protagonist.

At another point, they are fleeing from soldiers of a race I recall they referred to as "gargoyles."

In retrospect the art was much higher quality than the typical comic, and I'm curious about the story and its creator.

Comment: Reminds me of Monty Python's fish license sketch, all the customer's pets are called Eric.

Comment: Highly detailed comics with oddball plots sounds a lot like *Heavy Metal* -- or a graphic novel of a serial from that magazine.

Comment: Do you recall if it was in black and white or color?

Comment: @DanielRoseman A-one, two, A-one, two, three, four. Half a bee, philosophically, must ipso facto, half not be...